# How would you test this typical controller method?

Tags: php, unit-testing, model-view-controller, phpunit

I'm using PHPUnit to test my MVC application. Most of the code for my models (Site, MStudent, MMenu in this example) are well covered with unit tests, but I find it difficult to test the functions on my controllers. A typical controller function in my framework looks like this:

```
/**
 * List the mentor's students
 */
public function students()
{
    // set some variables needed in the view
    $menu = MMenu::init($this->mentor, "List of students");
    $filter = "";
    $students = array();

    $sql = "SELECT * "
            . "FROM {Site::app()->settings['tablePrefix']}students s "
            . "WHERE s.pID = {$this->mentor->id} "
            . "ORDER BY s.lastvisit DESC";

    $cmd = Site::app()->db()->prepare($sql);
    if ($cmd->execute() AND ($rows = $cmd->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)))
    {
        foreach ($rows as $row)
        {
            $students[] = new MStudent($row);
        }
    }

    // call the view
    include Site::app()->viewPath("manage/students");
    exit;
}
```

Is there something senseable to test in there? How would you test it?

**EDIT:**
So from Stephen's feedback, I can refactor and put the database access in the model:

```
public function students()
{
    // set some variables needed in the view
    $menu = MMenu::init($this->mentor, "List of students");
    $filter = "";

    $students = MStudent::studentsFromQuery("SELECT * FROM students WHERE pID=" . $this->mentor->id);

    // call the view
    include Site::app()->viewPath("manage/students");
    exit;
}
```

Now there is even less to test here. Does it make sense to test functions like these and how would one do it?

Comment: If this is MVC, then I think your controller is a little fat. Sure the database access should be in the model?

Comment: Yes, the database query should definitely be in the model.

Comment: I would put the whole query into the model to abstract away all SQL from the controllers. Create a method on `MStudent` such as `studentsForMentor($mentorId)`. Also, you're going to have a difficult time testing code that uses static methods.

Comment: Calling `exit` is also a killer for testing. At least put it in a `doExit()` method in your base controller that you can mock or disable during testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be noted that moving controller logic into the models does not preclude the need to test it in your controller tests! Whatever you move into the models will have to be mocked.

It's rare to have a controller that does so little that it can actually be unit tested in a way that makes it worthwhile (IMO). The cost/benefit to mocking all of the dependencies just doesn't pay off. Often controller methods are instead tested indirectly as part of system tests.

Comment: Looks like no-one in the SO community has a better answer so I accept yours as the way to go. Thank you for your helpful answer. It clarifies something that has been bugging me for quite a while.